# Firefox previous tab

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, browser-tabs, vimperator

Is it possible to go to the previously <s>active</s> open tab natively in Firefox or using Vimperator?

It is especially useful when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab and Firefox open it as **the last tab**, then I forgot what was the  previously active tab that I was reading on being unable to go back to that tab.

So I'm looking for a solution natively on Firefox, on Vimperator, or using addons.

Comment: The docs say [`CTRL+9`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) is what you're looking for, but I have add-ons that override that functionality ..

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Is it Firefox or Vimperator's feature?

Comment: It is a Firefox specific key-combo, but it didn't work for me either because of an add-on I use that overrides that key combo .. you might be able to use something like the [menu wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/) or [keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) extension to change this behavior to something that suits you though ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimperator provides you with two methods to get to the previous tab, which is knows as the "alternate buffer":

- `:b #` - This uses the shortcut for the buffers command and `#` marks the alternate buffer. You can find more info with `:help :b`.
- `<C-^>` - This is a shortcut to make the alternate buffer active.

Use whichever you like - or map them to something simpler if you wish.

Comment: Wow, that Ctrl+6 (even works without holding Shift to make a Caret ^) shortcut really works.  One thing I noted, it only goes back one time, meaning it won't go back two previous tabs, but that's fairly enough I guess.

Comment: "it only goes back one time" > Yes that's right. Vimperator is mimicking Vim's alternate file behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182852/in-vim-what-is-the-alternate-file

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Vimperator, but it is possible to make Firefox use the last-used order when switching tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (this means you can get back to the tab you were working on before hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, although just closing the tab still does *not* go back to the most recent one until you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Firefox default tab management kind of sucks.)

The setting you want is in **about:config**: `browser.ctrlTab.previews`. Set it to `True`. This will cause holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and tapping <kbd>Tab</kbd> to show previews of all open tabs, as you would expect, but it *also* changes the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) to switch between tabs in most-recently-used order (no, I don't know why that isn't a separate setting). If you don't *hold* the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, the switch will be instant and the preview won't even appear; it looks identical to the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior except it goes to the tab you actually wanted to go to.

I doubt Vimperator will interfere with this behavior, so hopefully changing that setting should solve the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I noticed the behaviour but didn't thought it was due to the change in order, but I already now about that key, it's especially good to use Ctrl+PgDown or PgUp to navigate in the default order when that key is set. I wonder if it's possible to go back to the previous tab in Firefox, which is very useful, without that key in `about:config` which changes the behaviour of many things as well.